# Measure up to 50um linear displacement with ~100nm accuracy

Tags: sensor, encoder, piezo

I am using some open loop, mechanically amplified piezoelectric (PZT) devices to make linear movements of up to 100um. PZT are well known for hysteresis characteristics thus its repeatability is not poor. Closed loop models are commercially available but are too expensive for my application and I do not really need that nanometer accuracy: ~100nm is good enough, plus I would only need a reading instead of a build-in feedback control. What would be my options to measure displacement of up to 100um at ~100nm accuracy?

Comment: I can expand on this if nobody else does. I'm not expert in this area. Interferometry of some sort.diffraction gratings. LVDT maybe but probably too small a range.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's purely a mechanical engineering question. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ may be more suitable.

Comment: @pipe I don't think this is related to mechanical. I've investigated related methods including laser TOF and magnetic/optical encoders, and none of them is mechanical but largely electrical. These methods are hardly sensitive enough, though.

Comment: moire fringes between fixed and moving gratings might do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capacitive micrometry is a well established method of measuring absolute displacements in this range.

Conceptually it is very simple - measure the change in capacitances(s) of a two or three plate capacitor. Quite likely that is what the closed loop systems use for feedback.

It’s a bit small sensitivity for an LVDT, but possible with a commercial system.

There are possible optical and magnetic methods too.